# Annual Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open - 2018

Tags: discussion, mvp

## Public service announcement:

The [MVP nominations](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2018/01/salesforce-mvp-2018-nominations.html?d=70130000000tP4G) are open from now until February 5th, 2018.

**NOTE: This is now an annual rather than Bi-annual process.** [Source](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/mvp/)

> New MVP classes will be welcomed **once per year**, and anyone can nominate an MVP during the **once-yearly** nomination period.

Feel free to nominate those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be users or moderators or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

See also: [Top 5 Things to Know About How We Choose Our MVPs](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/how-we-choose-salesforce-mvps.html)

Comment: I will be nominating Eric (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/3996/eric) for his outstanding contribution in SFSE, but couldn't find all the details which is needed to fill  the form. I am not sure if he is already a mvp.

Comment: @SantanuBoral That is the challenge with the nomination process. Salesforce need sufficient details so thay can get in contact with the individual nominated. Right now that mostly resolves around a known email address. Without that you can't complete the form.

Comment: @Eric Have you considered expanding your profile page. No problem if you don't feel like it, just a nudge.